# jaxb getter with parameter

Tags: jaxb, jax-ws

I've requirement where I've to pass a parameter in the getter method(in my case another object). Wondering if thats possible and how can I achieve this? I'm implementing jaxws and this is my server side requirement. When client is created, getMetaValues(..) method is not available.
my code is

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Revision implements Serializable {
     //other props and getter/setter
private List<Metavalue> metaValues;
@XmlElement    
 //Field is a custom class
public List<Metavalue> getMetaValues(Field field) {       
   metaValues=null;
    if (field!=null) {
        Map<String, Metakey> metadata = getMetadata();
        Metakey metakey = metadata.get(field.getName());
        if (metakey!=null) {
            metaValues = metakey.getMetavalues();
        }
    }        
    return metaValues;
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JAXB (JSR-222) implementations require a `get` method with no parameters.  You could specify `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` so that JAXB deals directly with the field instead.